# OpenGL - Rotations on different axis independent of eachother

Tags: opengl, rotation, lwjgl

First off, I'm sorry if I confuse anyone because I don't know how to phrase this, exactly.

Anyway, What I want to do is rotate on 3 axis, but independent of eachother. If I have

```
glRotatef(getPitch(),1f,0,0);
glRotatef(getYaw(),0,1f,0);
glRotatef(getRoll(),0,0,1f);
```

Then, it rotates my object on the x axis just fine, but the other two axis rotate on the offset of the x rotation. How do I rotate these all independent of eachother? (On the same object)

Again, Sorry if I confused anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You could push and pop the matrix onto and off the stack, so you could do:

```
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef( getPitch(), 1.0f, 0.0f ,0.0f );
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
glRotatef( getYaw(), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
glRotatef( getRoll(), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glPopMatrix();
```

so basically, pushing the matrix, saves the transformation matrix in it's current state. You apply the transformations that you want on the object (in your case rotations around an axis), which updates the matrix. Popping it restores it to the original state before the rotation was applied. You can then apply each rotation independently of the other ones.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to rotate the same object on all three axis independent of each other.

Comment: Could you give more details. What do you mean by the other two axis rotating on the offset of the x rotation? Personally, I would just store a rotation matrix, and incrementally apply the rotation (pitch, yaw, roll) on each axis, and then load it into OpenGL. Something similar to the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063293/opengl-sdl-rotation-around-local-axis).

Comment: A couple of resources if you're not using matrices in OpenGL yet (1) Matrix tutorial [link](http://bit.ly/1ECA2tp) for a matrix header class and tutorial on applying rotations and loading the resulting matrix to describe the orientation. (2) OpenGL Math library that includes a matrix type, as well as functions to apply rotations [link](http://bit.ly/1bEvnuu).